# what does the rake db:migrate:status output indicates ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have done some changes to the migration files after having some problems 
delete the last migration file and rollback.

Now when I run

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

I am getting a list with all the migrations on the last line
I am getting a record like this one

up 20130919172415 ************* NO FILE ********************

the timestamp in this record is the same with the one on schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20130918172415) do
```

My question is what does this record means and if I am going to have a problem
on the future on probable new migrations.

Answer (score 2):

the `****** NO FILE ******` is for migrations you've deleted.  They're only a problem if you didn't keep up with each migration.